# How to enable mic without muting sound in windows 10?

Tags: audio, io

I'm creating an app that plays a set of video clips or slides sequentially, advancing each time the user speaks "next" into the mic, replaying the clip or slide when the user says "repeat," and repeating the previous clip or slide when the user says "back." I want sound to accompany each clip or slide, so I don't want the sound muted. I'm not worried about feedback issues.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Why the sound is muted ? What are feedback issues ? What is your question ?